# in flutter i have build a dart isolate but it is not uploading files to server dart isolate not working perfectly in the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

```
// ignore_for_file: unused_local_variable

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:test/data/models/post_model.dart';

import '../../../functions/add_notification.dart';

 Future<void> uploadInBackground(
List<File> data, PostModel posts) async {
 try {
final ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();

await Isolate.spawn(_uploadIsolate, receivePort.sendPort);

// Create a completer to listen for the isolate response
final Completer<void> completer = Completer<void>();
receivePort.listen((dynamic message) {
  if (message is int) {
    print('undefine');
    // Update the progress in the notification
    updateNotificationProgress(message);
  }
   else {
    print('define');
    // Upload complete or failed, close the notification
    completer.complete();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(0);
     receivePort.close();
   }
});
final send = receivePort;
// Send the data to the isolate
send.sendPort.send({'images': data, 'posts': posts});

return completer.future;
 } catch (e) {
log('error in upload in backgroud');
 print(e);
}
}

// Isolate function
Future<void> _uploadIsolate(SendPort sendPort) async {
 print('running FIle');
try {
final ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
sendPort.send(receivePort.sendPort);

await for (dynamic message in receivePort) {
  print('Received message in isolate: $message');
  final List<File> files = message['images'];
  final PostModel posts = message['posts'];
  print(files);
  print(posts);
  final SendPort mainThreadSendPort = message['sendPort'];
  try {
    // Upload images to Firebase Storage
    final List<String> imageUrls =
        await _uploadImagesToStorage(files, mainThreadSendPort);

    // Store image URLs in Cloud Firestore
    await _storeImageUrlsInFirestore(imageUrls, posts);

    mainThreadSendPort.send('Upload complete');
  } catch (ex) {
    mainThreadSendPort.send('Upload failed');
  }
  sendPort.send('Upload complete');
}
;
// );
 } catch (ex) {
log('error in _upload Isolate');
   print(ex);
 }
}

// uploading function of images
Future<List<String>> _uploadImagesToStorage(
List<File> imageFiles, SendPort sendPort) async {
 final List<String> imageUrls = [];

 for (int i = 0; i < imageFiles.length; i++) {
final File imageFile = imageFiles[i];

final Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref('images')
    .child(
        
  
 'images/${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}_$i.${imageFiles[i].path.split('.').last}');
final UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(imageFile);

uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
  final double progress =
      (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
  sendPort.send(progress.toInt());
});

await uploadTask;

// Add the download URL to the list
  final String imageUrl = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
   imageUrls.add(imageUrl);
   }

    // Return the list of download URLs
  return imageUrls;
   }

   // store images in database
    Future<void> _storeImageUrlsInFirestore(
   List<String> imageUrls, PostModel data) async {
   data.images?.clear();
  data.images?.addAll(imageUrls);

  final imagesCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('User Posts')
  .add(data.toFirestore());

 // Store image URLs in Firestore
  }
```

this is my upload file in this file i have added ome print statements to check where is the problem occurring. and it gives  me prints in console they are
I/flutter ( 2883): uploading
I/flutter ( 2883): running FIle
I/flutter ( 2883): define
according to this in the fuction  _uploadIsolate the listening to port is not working . does any one know hat is it happening .
i already tried the  receivePort.listen property but it is also giving the same . this is a program for uploading the data to firebase.